# How can I batch images with arbitrary sizes in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Acually in Caffe, there seems exists a way to maintain the aspect ratio after resizing images such that the smaller dimension equaled 500 or else.

But I cannot find any way to solve this problem.

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04890.pdf), we can see that,

`We implemented our model using the Caffe library [15] and optimized it using SGD with momentum. Training on the AVA dataset’s approximately 250k training images took 2 weeks on a single Nvidia M40 GPU. Although our network can train and evaluate with images of arbitrary dimensions, very large images drastically decrease training and evaluation speed and pose memory issues due to GPU memory constraints. Therefore, in practice we resize each image such that the smaller image dimension equaled 500, while maintaining the original aspect ratio. This resulted in significant loss of resolution in some cases, but is a signifi- cantly higher resolution than is typically used for convolutional networks. We used a batch size of 128, a learning rate of 10−3 , momentum of 0.9 and weight decay of 5 · 10−4 . We reduced the learning rate after every 20k iterations. The convolutional layers were pre-trained on ImageNet [6].`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply resize the image as they say with your favorite library, for instance, you could use scipy.misc.imresize.